# Permissions in Chain of Program Execution

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I have a Java program that writes some files to `/tmp` and invokes some python processes. I'm wondering if both the Java program and the python processes have the same permissions as the user that originally executed the Java program?

Also, would the python processes be able to delete the files written by the Java program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, an program or script should run with the permissions of the process that started it, so as long as you don't have the `setuid` flag set on the python scripts, they should run as the same user as the Java program.

This means the python scripts *should* be able to delete the files created by the Java program. Of course, if the Java program still has the files open at the time, you will run into problems.

Comment: Thanks! Quick follow-up question, how does JVM/interpreters fit into this picture? Suppose that the JVM was started by one user, and another user executes the bytecode, how is permission defined here? Or does that even make sense? (I'm not familiar with Java)

Comment: @Max I am pretty sure that doesn't make sense.