# Relative Path in Chain of Process Call

Tags: linux, shell, path

I have a Java program which executes a bunch of python and shell scripts, which in turn will call some other python/shell scripts. If I use relative paths in any of the scripts, would the paths be based off where the original Java program was executed? Or would it be a different location?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permissions in Chain of Program Execution](http://superuser.com/questions/816257/permissions-in-chain-of-program-execution)

Comment: Try [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to locate it yourself.

Comment: @Raystafarian It isn't a *duplicate*. Both of these questions are *related* but they are two different things. This one asks about the **working directory** of these processes, while the question you linked to is about **file permissions**.

Comment: @Raystafarian not sure how these two questions both asked by me are duplicates :) one is about permission the other about relative path

Comment: @Max I am *pretty* sure it should be the same. Why don't you just try it and see though?

Comment: @lzam Thanks, and you are right I should try this. I figured I should ask here in case I miss some conceptual stuff or non-straight-forward rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't `cd`/`chdir` anywhere in your code, the paths are relative to your current directory when you launched the Java program (not the location of the Java program itself).